# ggraph package Installation

Tags: r, package

While trying to load package "ggraph" in R,encountered this message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggraph’: object ‘cividis’ is not exported by 'namespace:viridisLite'
```

Comment: There was a recent change to viridisLite. https://github.com/sjmgarnier/viridisLite/issues/8. Try reinstalling `viridisLite` with `install.packages("viridisLite")`

Comment: Error rectified. Thank you.